# angular best way to interact with the router from html text input

Tags: angular, froala

I use froala text editor to store some user inputs. 
I want to create some specific output in the html text which create links ables to interact with the router or with the app in general (call function in controllers and so on...).

What is the best way to "reinterpret" html links as routed links so the page won't be reload?

froala output:

```
<a href="/someRoute">some text</a>
```

will become after treatment:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/someRoute']">some text</a>
```

Edit:
**I don't need froala. I can create my own editor. But I need to convert html user input into router link or component functions**

Edit 2:
Is it possible to reinterpret html as

```
<app-mycomponent [someVariable]="someVariable"></app-mycomponent>
```

Here a skeleton of what I need:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnnw8n?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts

I can parse the html to find my specific tags and use *ngIf in the view

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let parsedHtml of arrayOfHtmlPart">
  <ng-container *ngIf="isHtml(parsedHtml)">
    {{parsedHtml}}
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!isHtml(parsedHtml)">
    <app-mycomponent></app-mycomponent>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

but it is not elegant

Comment: You can't. "Fraola" inputs are post-build inputs : once built, your application doesn't have `routerLink`s anymore. Try providing a [mcve] reproducing your use-case on https://stackblitz.io, and i might be able to provide a workaround for you.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I added some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nasiruddin Saiyed said, you should use Nasiruddin Saiyed @HostListener and then detect the A tags you want to be treated as router links. If the element class is set to 'content-inside', it will act has a router link (without reload)

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    public onClick(event) {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'A' && event.target.getAttribute('class') === 'content-inside') {
        this.router.navigate([event.target.getAttribute('href')]);
        event.preventDefault();
      } else {
        return;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [`@HostListener`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) and [`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) Binding Event and by following example of TableRow, in which i have performed  redirection using [`Router`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router):

This is the component declared in another component's HTML as

```
<app-table-row [takeMeTo]='"/redirected"'></app-table-row>
```

and this will be its actual component class

```
export class TableRowComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() takeMeTo:string;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
    onClick(btn) {
      console.log(this.takeMeTo);
      this.router.navigate([this.takeMeTo]);      
  };
  constructor(public router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6pupt) if you want to check the full flow and code.

Happy Coding!! :)

Comment: Thanks for your code. It is working! but I don't understand how do implement this from an html text

Comment: @jolineck you can refer to the links i have provided with `@HostListener and @Input`.